# Why does Stripe still allows users to pick business type after setting business?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I've been using Stripe for the payment section of my online marketplace for individuals, and for some reason, users are still seeing the `Choose Business Type` option, even though I've already preset this. It's still saying `Account Representative` and `Management and Ownership`, which is confusing users, who now think this is only for businesses. Does anybody know why?

Here my code to create accounts is:

```
    const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
        type: 'express',
        country: 'CA',
        business_type: 'individual',
        business_profile: {
            name: "Company Lessor",
            product_description: "One of Company's Lessors."
        }
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is doing this; you should reach out to Support for more help on this: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email